# How to Backup and Transfer Everything to Another WordPress Site?

Tags: backup, migration

After doing much research, I give up and finally decided to ask this question here. I have created a WordPress Theme locally on my computer, and I want to transfer everything (database, posts, pages, plugins, custom fields, custom post types, media etc.) to another WordPress site. Here what I did, but it is not working out for me, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong,

I have backed up my SQL database and upload it to the database of my new website. I also backed up my posts, pages etc. using the default WordPress plugin, and also upload it to my new website. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but it did not restore a thing.

So, my question is what is the best way and the easiest way to backup and transfer everything in WordPress?

P.S. These are the three plugins that I used to backup everything, [BackUpWordPress](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/), [Migrate DB](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/), and the default WordPress Import/Export Plugin.

Comment: Why did it not work? Did you get any errors from those plugins? Is this other site a fresh install? Or is there stuff there you want to keep as well.

Comment: off-topic note: it is a bad practice to transfer DB from a dev machine which might have garbage in it to a production.

Comment: @Nath, nope it didn't give any error at all when I uploaded the backup files. In fact, everything was uploaded successfully, but its giving me errors of the custom field variables that I have made, which means it wasn't a successful transfer. Yes, I am trying to upload to a fresh installed WordPress site.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, I know... That is why I never done that before. Since my client didn't give me an access, that is why I decided to develop the theme locally. I guess the biggest mistake I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) and it works perfectly every time.

A lot of site configuration information, including URLs, is stored in the database and this plugin is pretty good at figuring out how to make the necessary changes, including where info is serialised.

Comment: Awesome plugin...!!! Thank you so much for introducing it to me. Its like plug and play...